# Can't run file.rb from command prompt

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

i have Ruby 2.2 and i can't run any file .rb from command prompt each time i have same error:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/win32.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-5.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/watir/loader.rb:41:in `load_driver'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-5.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/watir/loader.rb:33:in `load_driver_for'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-5.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/watir/loader.rb:14:in `start'
        from test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

what shall i do?

Comment: https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/issues/73

Comment: Watir classic is no longer in active development, you should update your tests to use the watir-webdriver gem

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked when i changed to watir-webdriver

Comment: can you tell me the difference between Watir classic and Watir webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1
```